# Is there any way to convert SilkTest into C#

Tags: decompiling, disassembly, silktest

I am trying to figure out a way to reliably convert SilkTest scripts into C#.

The only idea I have come up with so far is disassembling a SilkTest binary then decompiling it. However, I can't find a way to get a SilkTest binary from a SilkTest `.t` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A .t file is text that contains the automation for your test case written in the 4Test language which is the language that Silk Test Classic, there is nothing to disassemble or decompile.

If you want your test case to be in C# consider using Silk4Net rather than Silk Test Classic.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: No.

This feature has been [requested for Visual Test scripts since 2012 (Uservoice)](http://borland.uservoice.com/forums/163510-silk-test-feature-request/suggestions/3117545-silktest-workbench-convert-visual-test-to-net-sc) but never been implemented.

I have asked the question for [4Test scripts (Uservoice)](http://borland.uservoice.com/forums/163510-silk-test-feature-request/suggestions/6125380-converting-silktest-classic-tests-to-silk4j) and got the following response:

> Please get in touch with support, to information about how to migrate from Silk Test Classic to Silk4J.

Unfortunately, the response from MicroFocus support was: "Automatic conversion is not possible. But they can recommend a company which does such a conversion as a service provider".